# Using System.Globalization.CultureInfo from VBScript

Tags: .net, com, vbscript, activex, cultureinfo

I can't figure out how to use the .NET class: `System.Globalization.CultureInfo`.

According to the [documentation](http://%3Chttp://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx%3E), it has `ComVisibleAttribute = True`, which I thought meant I could use it from VBScript. However, when I try to use it like:

```
Set ci = CreateObject("System.Globalization.CultureInfo")
```

I get:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error: ActiveX component can't create object: 'System.Globalization.CultureInfo'
```

Perhaps I am misunderstanding something, and this class simply cannot be used from VBScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible... `CultureInfo` has no parameterless constructor, and `CreateObject` doesn't allow you to specify constructor arguments

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: The list of .NET Framework classes accessible from VBScript is under the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT registry key:
[image: COM-callable .NET classes]
The `System.Globalization.CultureInfo` class isn't there, so it is not scriptable.

Techy answer: COM interopability prerequisites for .NET classes are described in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7fcfby2t.aspx), and as Thomas said, the `CultureInfo` class doesn't qualify because it lacks a parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 1):

[CreateObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dcw63t7z%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) creates and returns a reference to an **Automation object**. COM object is not an automation object in common case.

I guess that System.Globalization.CultureInfo doesn't support IDispatch, so you cannot use it in VBScript.